# How do I add guidelines to draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

As options guidelines can be enabled and disabled. There is no option to add guidelines neither help about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guidelines are there to help you align elements to each other.

Try the following: On an empty canvas add two boxes, and change the size of one of the boxes. Then start dragging the smaller box around the larger box. Now you'll see that the guidelines will appear when the edges of the boxes align, or when the center of the boxes align.

This can be very helpful when you have multiple boxes and you want to order them properly. You can then align them using the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the behaviour of this guidelines. Then, I think the name is not full descriptive of his function. In all other design programs this function is _snap_ to edges, borders, vertices, middle, etc... And guidelines are static and permanent (once created and not edited). Instead, these guidelines are dynamic and momentary.

Comment: Guidelines _are_ supposed to be dynamic, to help you guide your design. The snapping functionality is another beast (also present in draw.io), as are also the grid lines. :-)